# Take data from database with javascript

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, xmlhttprequest, fetch

In a Javascript function I need data from the database.

What should I use `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch()` or `Ajax`*?

I tryed the first one but somewhere I read is old and `fetch()` is to be prefered. Is that true?

I'm a beginner, anyway my `file.js`:

```
function FilterBy(selezione) {
...
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      };
      //xhttp.open("GET", "lists/getlistname/?m="+maschio+"&f="femmina+"&n="neutro+"&l="linguaggio+"&i="initial", true);
      //xhttp.open("GET", "/lists/getlistname/?maschio=True", true);
      xhttp.open("GET", "/lists/getlistname/", true);
      //xhttp.send("m="+maschio+"&f="+femmina+"&n="neutro+"&l="linguaggio+"&i="initial");
      xhttp.send("maschio=True&femmina=False&neutro=False&linguaggio=romano&initial=a");
}
```

I made some tentative but the parameters doesn't arrive to my view. Also can I use a url django style, like `lists:getlistname`?

here my `url.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('getlistname/', views.getlistname, name='getlistname'),
]
```

my `views.py`:

```
def getlistname(request, maschio=True, femmina=True, neutro=True,
                linguaggio='tutti', initial='0'):
    ...
    return HttpResponse('hi')
```

So, what happens? the view `getlistname` is called but the parameters aren't passed (it uses the default).

*Note: for using Ajax I mean something like this:

```
    $.ajax({type: 'GET',
        url: '/lists/getnamelist/',
        data: {
            maschio: True,
            femmina: True
            ...
        },
        success: function () {
        ...
        }
    });
```

Edit: at last I used $.ajax() because for what I read it's less efficient but cleaner

Comment: Hi I would like to recommend you to use something like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) is lightweight and has a lot of features, and if you can not add libraries to your project, I think you should use ```fetch api```

Answer (score 1):

You need server side work to be done, a method or a class inside views. It depends on your database model. Afterwards you can get the results using javascript, but solely based on js you cannot access the database.

in your case just for "Hi" message yes you can do it using an ajax. Let me know if you would like some data from database or just a string.

For database:
You can create a method:

```
def data_get(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = dataModel.objects.all()
        # you can process data into mylist or another method to do that
    return return render(request, "yoururl.html", {'mylist' : mylist})
```

Then you can get this data inside your html. You will need to post a form for that.

There are many other ways of course.

Comment: I need data but I think to can do that. I have to work on return. I already have a view where I retrive the data, even if I'm using GET (probabily for size and security I'll change in POST) and I'm not checking for the method (`if request.method ==`). The problem is that my view don't accept the parameters I'm sending with my XMLHttpRequest. The variable `maschio`, for example, is always `True` (the default) even if i 'm sending a `False`

Comment: you have to send parameters, within form using post. create a form and post it.